# Best way to save multiple sensor for later processing?

Tags: ros, rosbag, bagfile

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I need to record all the data my robot collects from its sensors for later processing. ( LIDAR, Kinect, Stereo Cam, Thermal Cam, IMU, Odometry,...)
So the first option that came to my mind, was to save it in a bag file.
I didn't try it but I heard, that it could be a problem for the ROS bag to record data from that many sensors.
And I don't know any other packages that could help me in this case.

So if someone has experience with that or knows some other tools, please tell me. :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54100/best-way-to-save-multiple-sensor-for-later-processing?/) by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 496 on 2013-02-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Bag files works fine. I have you are storing images then its size could be a problem otherwise it works fine.

PS: Dont forget to store tf with sensor readings.

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-02-03**:
If you are storing images, you can select compressed versions.